# MySQL with docker Access denied

Tags: mysql, database, docker

I need to use MySQL on docker. The steps I've followed :

1. Installed docker
2. Pulled MySQL docker image
3. Ran docker container for MySQL
4. Installed MySQL client.

But When I run this

```
sudo docker exec -it mysql8 MySQL -uroot -p
```

It asks for a password, I enter the password and it gives me this :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password : Yes)
```

How do I fix this and what am I missing?
I followed the tutorial here :
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-deploy-and-use-a-mysql-docker-container/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you have followed is outed and also running container and the change password is not the proper way when working in the container. With Offical image, you can set using environment variable.

use below command and further details you can find on [Mysql Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass -d mysql
```

then try to connect

```
docker exec -it some-mysql bash -c "mysql -u root -pmypass"
```

Comment: There are other way around to avoid this but you can look into questions, it's about leaking the password it's about not able to make connection, I can update questions accordingly if that's the only objection from your side but down vote before asking clarification is not the way to deal @Ron

Comment: If the OP having an issue to connect with DB, it means he is learner so that was the least secure solution to him but have no password is really risky. off course my answer will be different if OP is like you :) also when it comes to docker if some have access to  host OS he can access any thing inside docker @RonvanderHeijden

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a docker container for mysql, you can use this command given below.

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3308:3306 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

You can also set more environment variables for mysql in this given command.

In order to access mysql inside this container you have 2 easy ways:

1. Use docker exec -it container_name. Then write mysql -u root -p inside the container or along with the command given is your wish.
2. Use mysql client and access from local itself.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
Have to run

```
docker logs <container_name>
```

which gives a generated password using which we have to use when prompted for password.

Afterward, we can change the password by :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Comment: This helped! 

This led to learning that setting MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD to no, actually sets it to true: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html

I thus removed the mention of environment variable and was able to log in using the password specified with MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.